# Firestore Chron trigger cloud function erroring out

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, tslint

I'm trying to implement a function that triggers every day and targets my "task" collection, which features documents that have a 'performAt' field. If the performAt field is in the past, I want to set it to a time 24 hours in the future.

Note: in the case of this example to get it working, I've made the chron job scheduled for every minute.

```js
export const dailyJob = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(async context => {
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
    const nowMill = now.toMillis();
    const tomorrowMill = nowMill + 8.28e+7;
    const tomorrow = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(tomorrowMill);

    const query = db.collection('tasks').where('performAt', '<=', now).where('worker', '==', 'dailyJob');
    const tasks = await query.get();

    tasks.forEach(snapshot => {
        snapshot.ref.update({performAt: tomorrow})
    });
})
```

Unfortunately, this code is erroring when I try to deploy it to Firestore. Anyone have any idea why it would be terminating?

Error log below

```js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: @M.R. I added the error message above, but I do not think it provides much.

Comment: You're missing the best part of the error.  What's immediately above what you pasted?  That's where the error output of tslint is telling you what it doesn't like in your code.